# Best way to select fields to optimize queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a social network and I need to optimize it. I searched and tested (local) I think I can win 30% of performance if I select fields for my queries. **Am I right? Or it will not change?**

Actualy when I write a query I write like this :

```
public function getNewsfeed($count) {

    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
                ->leftJoin('n.sender', 'u')
                    ->addSelect('u')
                ->orderBy('n.id', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults($count);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

So this give me this :

```
SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.type AS type1, n0_.data AS data2, n0_.reference AS reference3, n0_.date AS date4, f1_.username AS username5, f1_.username_canonical AS username_canonical6, f1_.email AS email7, f1_.email_canonical AS email_canonical8, f1_.enabled AS enabled9, f1_.salt AS salt10, f1_.password AS password11, f1_.last_login AS last_login12, f1_.locked AS locked13, f1_.expired AS expired14, f1_.expires_at AS expires_at15, f1_.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token16, f1_.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at17, f1_.roles AS roles18, f1_.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired19, f1_.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at20, f1_.id AS id21, f1_.user_ip AS user_ip22, f1_.name AS name23, f1_.avatar AS avatar24, f1_.birthday AS birthday25, f1_.sex AS sex26, f1_.city AS city27, f1_.country AS country28, f1_.last_activity AS last_activity29, f1_.warning AS warning30, f1_.status AS status31, f1_.notification AS notification32, f1_.visitor AS visitor33, f1_.friend AS friend34, f1_.message AS message35, f1_.antiflood AS antiflood36, f1_.wantmail AS wantmail37, f1_.autodestruction AS autodestruction38, f1_.suspended AS suspended39, n0_.sender_id AS sender_id40, f1_.profil_id AS profil_id41 FROM newsfeed n0_ LEFT JOIN fos_user f1_ ON n0_.sender_id = f1_.id ORDER BY n0_.id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Has you can see, it's very long. I don't need email, password, etc. I searched on Stack how to select fields with doctrine and the only way who works it's like this :

```
public function getNewsfeed($count) {

    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
                ->select('partial n.{id, type, reference, data, date}')
                ->leftJoin('n.sender', 'u')
                    ->addSelect('partial u.{id, name, avatar, roles, sex, last_activity, suspended}')
                ->orderBy('n.id', 'DESC')
                ->setMaxResults($count);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

It's give me a query more small :

```
SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.type AS type1, n0_.data AS data2, n0_.reference AS reference3, n0_.date AS date4, f1_.roles AS roles5, f1_.id AS id6, f1_.name AS name7, f1_.avatar AS avatar8, f1_.sex AS sex9, f1_.last_activity AS last_activity10, f1_.suspended AS suspended11, n0_.sender_id AS sender_id12, f1_.profil_id AS profil_id13 FROM newsfeed n0_ LEFT JOIN fos_user f1_ ON n0_.sender_id = f1_.id ORDER BY n0_.id DESC LIMIT 15
```

So I've 2 questions :

1. I'll really win many performance if I select fields ?
2. It's the best way? Or you've an another method for selecting fields?

Thanks for you time and sorry for my newbie questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely it will affect performance.

For simple/small data, the cost is minimal. However, if you have `BLOB`s or something similar, well, you get the picture - server just needs time to fetch and transport all the data to `PHP`. From `Doctrine`'s point of view, if you have related entities, you don't have to waste additional time to create `Proxy` objects.

If you wish to preserve an object model for some  model use `PARTIAL` as you did above.

You could squeeze extra bit of performance if you choose not to preserve the object model, for example, if you plan to send data immediately after to client:

```
$data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

The downside is that you cannot use getters/setters anymore.

### Side note:

Term `optimize` goes hand-in-hand with caches. Given that you are building a social network, have you considered using one? :)

Comment: Yes I think I must preserve object for Twig template. I've cache for common blocks : last users, last forum topics, but the rest I can't : forum, chat, instant message (pv), member search, profil, comments, newsfeed etc.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you don't need to preserve object model in order to render data in `Twig`... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize I recommend using Stored Procedure and map it with ResultSetMapping and notice in this example that I implement in my application that has three layers:

**1.- Interface**

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

interface BaseRepositoryInterface 
{
    public function _getByFilters($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars);

    public function _getOneResult($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars);

    public function _add($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars);

    public function _update($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars);

    public function _recordCnt($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars);

    public function _pages($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars, $size);

    public function generateArgs(array $vars, $sql);
}
```

**2.- implementation**

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

class BaseSpRepository extends EntityRepository implements BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function _getByFilters($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars) {
        list($sql, $parameters) = $this->generateArgs($vars, $sp);
        $this->clear();

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getResult();
    }

    public function _getOneResult($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars) {
        $result = $this->_getByFilters($sp, $rsm, $vars);

        if (count($result) < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return array_shift($result);
    }

    public function _add($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars) {
        $result = array();
        list($sql, $parameters) = $this->generateArgs($vars, $sp);
        $this->clear();

        $result = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getResult();

        if (count($result) == 1)
            $result = $result[0];

        return $result;
    }

    public function _update($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars) {
        return $this->_add($sp, $rsm, $vars);
    }

    public function _pages($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars, $size = 10) {
        $result = array();
        list($sql, $parameters) = $this->generateArgs($vars, $sp);
        $this->clear();

        $result = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getResult();

        if (count($result) > 0)
            $result = array_values($result[0])[0];

        if (($result % $size) > 0)
            return intval($result / $size) + 1;

        return intval($result / $size);
    }

    public function _recordCnt($sp, ResultSetMapping $rsm, array $vars) {
        $result = array();
        list($sql, $parameters) = $this->generateArgs($vars, $sp);
        $this->clear();

        $result = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->getResult();

        if (count($result) > 0)
            return array_values($result[0])[0];

        return 0;
    }

    public function generateArgs(array $vars, $sql) {
        $parameters = array();
        $wheres = array();
        $sql = sprintf('EXEC %s', $sql);

        if (count($vars) > 0) {
            $keys = array_keys($vars);

            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                $wheres[] = sprintf('@%s = :%s', $k, $k);

                if ($this->validateDate($vars[$k])) {
                    $date = new \DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', trim($vars[$k])));

                    $parameters[$k] = $date;
                } else if (preg_match('/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/', $vars[$k])) {
                    $parameters[$k] = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $vars[$k]));
                } else {
                    $parameters[$k] = $vars[$k];
                }
            }

            $sql = implode(" ", array($sql, implode(",", $wheres)));
        }

        return array($sql, $parameters);
    }

    private function validateDate($date, $format = 'd/m/Y') {
        $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
    } 
}
```

**3.- Example of how to apply the base model**

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use YourBundle\Entity\Repository\BaseSpRepository;

class DriverRepository extends BaseSpRepository
{
    private function getRsm($type = 'a') {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

        switch ($type) {
            case 'a':
                $rsm->addEntityResult('YourBundle\Entity\Driver', 'd');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'driverId', 'id');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'dni', 'dni');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'names', 'names');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'lastNames', 'lastNames');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'license', 'license');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'register', 'register');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'revalidationAt', 'revalidationAt');
                $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('YourBundle\Entity\LicenseCategory', 'lc', 'd', 'licenseCategory');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('lc', 'licenseCategoryId', 'id');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('lc', 'licenseCategoryName', 'name');
                $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('YourBundle\Entity\Provider', 'p', 'd', 'provider');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'providerId', 'id');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'providerName', 'name');
                break;
            case 'b':
                $rsm->addEntityResult('YourBundle\Entity\Driver', 'd');
                $rsm->addScalarResult('recordCnt', 'd');
                break;
            case 'c':
                $rsm->addEntityResult('YourBundle\Entity\Driver', 'd');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'id', 'id');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'dni', 'dni');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'license', 'license');
                $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'register', 'register');
                break;
        }

        return $rsm;
    }

    public function getByFilters(array $vars = array()) {
        return $this->_getByFilters("usp_drivers_index", $this->getRsm(), $vars);
    }

    public function getOneResult(array $vars = array()) {
        return $this->_getOneResult("usp_drivers_index", $this->getRsm(), $vars);
    }

    public function add(array $vars = array()) {
        return $this->_add("usp_drivers_add", $this->getRsm(), $vars);
    }

    public function update(array $vars = array()) {
        return $this->_update("usp_drivers_edit", $this->getRsm(), $vars);
    }

    public function pages(array $vars = array(), $size = 10) {
        return $this->_pages("usp_drivers_record_count", $this->getRsm('b'), $vars, $size);
    }

    public function exist(array $vars = array()) {
        return $this->_getByFilters("usp_drivers_check_if_exist", $this->getRsm('c'), $vars);
    }
}
```